# Programmatically dropping a `group_by` field in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm writing functions that take in a `data.frame` and then do some operations. I need to add and subtract items from the `group_by` criteria in order to get where I want to go.

If I want to add a `group_by` criteria to a df, that's pretty easy:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
n <- 10
input <- data.frame(a = 'a', 
                    b = 'b' , 
                    vals = 1
)

input %>%
  group_by(a) -> 
grouped 

grouped
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#> # Groups:   a [1]
#>   a     b      vals
#>   <fct> <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 a     b        1.

## add a group:
grouped %>% 
  group_by(b, add=TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#> # Groups:   a, b [1]
#>   a     b      vals
#>   <fct> <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 a     b        1.

## drop a group?
```

But how do I programmatically drop the grouping by `b` which I added, yet keep all other groupings the same?

Answer (score 11):

Here's an approach that uses tidyeval so that bare column names can be used as the function arguments. I'm not sure if it makes sense to convert the bare column names to text (as I've done below) or if there's a more elegant way to work directly with the bare column names.

```
drop_groups = function(data, ...) {

  groups = map_chr(groups(data), rlang::quo_text)
  drop = map_chr(quos(...), rlang::quo_text)

  if(any(!drop %in% groups)) {
    warning(paste("Input data frame is not grouped by the following groups:", 
                  paste(drop[!drop %in% groups], collapse=", ")))
  }

  data %>% group_by_at(setdiff(groups, drop))

}

d = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, vs, am)

groups(d %>% drop_groups(vs, cyl))
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> am
> ```

```
groups(d %>% drop_groups(a, vs, b, c))
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> cyl
>
> [[2]]
> am
>
> Warning message:
> In drop_groups(., a, vs, b, c) :
>   Input data frame is not grouped by the following groups: a, b, c
> ```

**UPDATE:** The approach below works directly with quosured column names, without converting them to strings. I'm not sure which approach is "preferred" in the tidyeval paradigm, or whether there is yet another, more desirable method.

```
drop_groups2 = function(data, ...) {

  groups = map(groups(data), quo)
  drop = quos(...)

  if(any(!drop %in% groups)) {
    warning(paste("Input data frame is not grouped by the following groups:", 
                  paste(drop[!drop %in% groups], collapse=", ")))
  }

  data %>% group_by(!!!setdiff(groups, drop))

}
```

Comment: I was just about to ask this as a separate question. Fantastic!

Answer (score 10):

Maybe something like this to remove grouping variables from the end of the list back:

```
grouped %>% 
 group_by(b, add=TRUE) -> grouped
grouped %>% group_by_at(.vars = group_vars(.)[-2])
```

or use `head` or `tail` or something on the output from `group_vars` for more control.

It would be interesting to have this sort of utility function available more generally:

```
peel_groups <- function(.data,n){
  .data %>%
    group_by_at(.vars = head(group_vars(.data),-n))
}
```

A more thought out version would likely include more careful checks on `n` being out of bounds.

Comment: @Ryan I actually hadn't thought of removal by name (potentially from inside the chain, not at the end) and think it's different enough to warrant undeleting your answer.

Comment: great ideas... I'm ramping up my `dplyr` foo so I had not realized there were `group_by` variants. is it possible for me to dump the original groupings into an object then later regroup by those? That would get me to the same place. (not a general solution to dropping one grouping, but solves my issue)

Comment: @JDLong Save the character vector from `group_vars()` and then reuse it sometime later with `group_by_at()`? That's essentially all my answer is doing...

Comment: @ryan, I think your answer is the right one for me. I'm going to use it whether you undelete or not ;)

Comment: @joran ... oh... yeah I see that now. I was typing faster than I can grok

Answer (score 8):

Function to remove groups by column name

```
drop_groups_at <- function(df, vars){
  df %>% 
    group_by_at(setdiff(group_vars(.), vars))
}


input %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>% 
  drop_groups_at('b') %>% 
  group_vars

# [1] "a"
```

Comment: aaaaaand... new question coming on how to make this work with tidyeval :)

Comment: @JDLong Seems like eipi10 just answered that one