# Ungroup some but not all variables in R + dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

In `dplyr` with R, if I've grouped by multiple variables can I then ungroup by a subset of those with `ungroup`? As far as I can tell, `ungroup` ignores any arguments provided and always ungroups everything.

Example:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>%
  # this removes 'am' but grouping by 'cyl' and 'vs' remain
  summarize(n = n()) %>%  
  ungroup(vs)  # I want this to work but it ungroups everything, not just 'vs'
```

Is there a way to remove the grouping by `vs` while keeping the grouping by `cyl`? I can accomplish this via

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%  
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(cyl)
```

but I feel like there has to be a better way than removing both groupings and re-adding just the `cyl` grouping.

I'm using the `summarize` in my examples because that's my particular context, but this behavior seems to be evident even in something as minimal as this:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs) %>%
  ungroup(vs)  # ungroups everything, not just 'vs'
```

---

**Update**: Thanks everyone for the great suggestions and comments. I just tried this and it works with no fuss due to `add=FALSE` in `group_by`, and it's as clean as what I was hoping `ungroup` could do:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%  
  group_by(cyl)
```

Thanks to @camille and @julius-vainora I know that `ungroup` by itself cannot do this, so I'll have to do grouping rather than ungrouping. @RyanD's suggestions were also very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programatically dropping a \`group\_by\` field in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237708/programatically-dropping-a-group-by-field-in-dplyr)

Comment: It is a little odd, since `ungroup`'s `...` argument implies that it should take column names and do something with them. There's actually an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3760) discussing how to implement this, but it doesn't seem to be in `dplyr` yet.

Comment: By looking at the source of each of `methods("ungroup")` one can see that `...` is never used. So it seems to be impossible with `ungroup`.

Comment: Luckily eipi10 has created a `drop_groups` function in the other question I linked.

Comment: @RyanD thanks for the link, that's very helpful. In my case I'm not doing it programmatically, I just wanted the code to be as clear as possible, so I can get by using `group_by(..., add=FALSE)` which I just learned about

Comment: A quick update from the dplyr documentation:
"You can also choose to selectively ungroup by listing the variables you want to remove:
by_sex_gender %>% 
  ungroup(sex) %>% 
  tally()"
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html

Comment: So I'm confused by the update. Do we need to simply do something like this:
```mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs, am, add = FALSE) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%  
  group_by(cyl)```
to only be grouped by cyl or we don't need to do anything just simply group_by(cyl) in the last line of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question based on present dplyr documentation:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html

"You can also choose to selectively ungroup by listing the variables you want to remove:"

```
by_sex_gender %>% 
  ungroup(sex) %>% 
  tally()
```